# CSS pseudo before/after different inheritance

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Is it possible for a pseudo element like `:before` or `:after` to inherit a value from a different property of the parent?

In my case I have a third party component that sets the background color of its elements Runtime... I need to inherit that color and set it to the border color of the pseudo elements.

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: I'm quite clumsy with css but if i set inherit in pseudo border-bottom-color it inherits from the parent border-bottom-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't inherit the value of a different property. This isn't any different between pseudo-elements and actual elements.